# Ionic/MobileFirst app automatically redirecting page

Tags: ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic3, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a following flow in my Ionic 3 app which is powered with MobileFirst Platform V8:

```
WelcomePage --> HomePage --> ViewReportPage
```

When user opens a app he will land on `WelcomePage` where he enters his credentials. Once a credentials are validated then he will be taken to `HomePage` from where he will click `View` button to go to `ViewReportPage`.

In the `ViewReportPage` user clicks the search button to search the reports.

My problem is, when user clicks the search button then as soon as the service code sends the request to fetch the data from the server, I am getting redirected to `HomePage`. Don't know whats the problem is. Below is the code.

Strange thing is, this is only happening if I close the app and opens it and then follow the steps given above. If I go ViewReportPage after being redirected to HomePage and then click search button then I am not facing this issue and the app is working as it should.

**ViewReportPage HTML**

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-list no-lines>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="year">
          <ion-option value="{{yearToSearch}}" *ngFor="let yearToSearch of years">{{yearToSearch}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <button round center padding class="align-center" color="secondary" ion-button (click)="search()">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-search" md="md-search" class="ion-lable-icon-padding"></ion-icon>
          Search
        </button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
```

**ViewReport TS**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-view-report',
  templateUrl: 'view-report.html',
})
export class ViewReportPage {
  public years : number[] = null; 
  public year = null;
  public corrData : any[] = null;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public loginSrvc : LoginService,
              public corrSrvc : ReportService,
              public events: Events) {
    let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.year =  currentYear;
    this.years = [
      currentYear,
      currentYear -1 ,
      currentYear - 2
    ];

    this.events.subscribe('corrResults',(value)=>{
      this.corrData = this.corrSrvc.getReportData();
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello ViewReportPage Page');
  }

  search(){
    let searchData : ReportSearchModel = new ReportSearchModel(
      this.loginSrvc.getUserId(),
      this.loginSrvc.getEncodedSignature(),
      this.year,
      null
    );  
    let invocationData = {
        procedure : 'getReports',
        parameters : searchData,
        navController : this.navCtrl
      };
      this.corrSrvc.search(invocationData);
  }
}
```

**ReportService TS**

```
search(invocationData){        
    let procedureName = invocationData.procedure;
    let parameters = invocationData.parameters;
    let nav : NavController = invocationData.navController;
    this.nav = nav;
    let isuserLoggedIn = this.loginService.checkForLoggedInUser();
    this.ngZone.run(
     () => {
        let reqToSend = new WLResourceRequest('/adapters/MyMFPAdapter'+procedureName, WLResourceRequest.GET);
        let jsonToStingData = JSON.stringify(parameters);
        reqToSend.setQueryParameter("params", `[${jsonToStingData}]`);
        reqToSend.send().then((response) => {
          let invocationResponse = response.responseJSON;
          //resolve(response.responseJSON);
          console.log(invocationResponse);
          this.corrData = invocationResponse['reportBeans'];
          if(this.corrData == null || this.corrData == undefined || this.corrData.length < 1){
            alert('No Report Found');
          }
          this.events.publish('corrResults','results');
        });
      }
    );        
  }

  getCorrespondenceData(){
    return this.corrData;
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting response from server while you doing resource request call during page redirection?

Comment: @VittalPai Yes I am getting the successful response.